# Get SPList and SharePoint.Client.List web relative url

Tags: url, sharepoint, relative-url, splist

I am working with sharepoint list and sharepoint client list objects. Is there any way to get web relative urls of those objects?
I know about ServerRelativeUrl, DefaultViewUrl but they don't solve my problem.
I want exactly web relative urls, without view url parts.
For example my tasks list has a url like this

```
http://example.com/sites/developer/lists/tasks/CustomDefaultView.aspx
```

and i want only `lists/tasks` part. 
For example my shared documents has a url like this

```
http://example.com/sites/developer/shared%20documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx
```

and i want only `shared%20documents` part. 
I need this both for SPList class and for SharePoint.Client.List class
thanks!

Answer (score 3):

So i found the solution. I need to use `SPList.RootFolder.Url` which returns Web site-relative url of the list(just what i want), and also need to do some manipulations for `Client.List` class as has no `RootFolder.Url` property, instead it has `RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl`. So if i subtract the server relative url of the parent web of that list from `RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl` i will get what i wanted for `Client.List` class.